# Can not see windows phone 7 emulator in visual studio 2012

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I can not see windows phone 7 emulator in visual studio 2012, I need to debug a wp7 project with visual studio 2012, but it seems that the windows phone 7 emulator doesn't attach on visual studio, anyone has ideas on it?

Comment: Did you solve this issue? I'd like to know how...

Answer (score 1):

Did you install the Windows Phone SDK?
If yes, go to your project properties and make sure that the targeted output is the emulator.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the needed SDK for Visual Studio 2012.

[Please find the link here](http://dev.windowsphone.com/en-us/downloadsdk)

SDK 8.0 itself have the emulator for WP7 also.

Answer (score 0):

Try reinstalling the SDK. I had simillar issue.